# Trying to use Autofill on a form with DLookup and not getting the correct results

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have 2 forms (Estimates & Jobs).  On the Estimate the field for Contractor is a drop down list from another table.  When I use the lookup wizard it changes to data type to number.  This works fine on the Estimate form.  On the Jobs Form I used the below code to autofill the Job Name and the Contractor fields.

This works fine for the Job Name but in the Contractor field it fills in the ID number not the Contractor's name. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub EstimateNumber_AfterUpdate()

    PopulateFields
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateFields()

''''PopulateFields will automatically fill in the Job Name and Contract Name from the Estimate Table

    JobName = RTrim(DLookup("EName", "Estimates", "Estimate=" & EstimateNumber))
    Contractor = RTrim(DLookup("EContractor", "Estimates", "Estimate=" & EstimateNumber))
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the bound column for the Contractor combo box. It is probably bound to the ID number and not Name

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your quick response.  I changed the bound column to the correct one but it didn't solve the problem - still not filling in the name.

Comment: When you select something in the combo box now does it display the name when manually selected? If that is working then you probably now need to update the Contractor Dlookup to get the ID

Comment: Yes, the combo box displays the name when I am using it on the Estimates Form.  The DLookup grabs the information from that form.  How would I change the DLookup to grab the ID?  Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: I think you are confused about the DLookup, it grabs the value from the table not the Form. So whatever your ID field is called in `Estimates` needs to go in your DLookup like so `Contractor = RTrim(DLookup("EContractorID", "Estimates", "Estimate=" & EstimateNumber))`

Comment: Sorry, got caught up in other stuff.  Thank you so much, your advice worked.